# How to publish extension on Firefox in beta version

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to publish my extension on Firefox for beta testing team. So someone can express me how to do this.
Or any steps to do them, it will be more help for me.

Answer (score 0):

AMO (addons.mozilla.org) no longer accepts beta versions for listed publication. You can upload your add-on as **unlisted** which means it can be signed and installed for testing.

Unlisted add-ons will have to be distributed by the developers.